# Variation of pressure of a gas in any accelerating container

Tags: pressure

[image]

Like the picture shown above the container contains a liquid with density 'rho' and the container is given an acceleration towards right and so by considering that any liquid section is also having the same acceleration as that of the container we can find out the pressure variation by using Newton's laws of motin .
But if there were a gas instead of liquid would its  pressure also vary like that of the liquid? 
And if it varies then can we find out the variation of pressure inside the gas like the same way we have found out in case of the liquid? Since gas and liquids both are fluids and share a large number of common properties .
And both the liquid and the gas in this context must be assumed as ideal .
And the container in which the gas would be kept is totally closed.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are intending to carry this activity out with a gas. If the container is not closed as shown above , there would be diffusion of gas to atmosphere which would need to be taken into consideration.

Comment: Oh I am sry please assume that the container is totally closed

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is "yes". The preassure of gas/liquid in different parts of the container would be $$ \Delta{P} = \rho g \Delta{h} + \rho a \Delta{l} $$ (it depends on both $x$ and $y$ position in the container).

Note, effects of gravity and "moving with acceleration" are very similar. Actually they are indistinguishable (that is "principle of equivalence").

Comment: Wouldn't density be a function of position, since it is a gas.

Comment: But how can we relate the pressure variation in gases just like that of a liquid the pressure of liquid changes with height but it's not so for an ideal gas

Comment: @VaishakhSreekanthMenon You are right, the density of gas is a function of position. But in usual scales (if we are talking about some tank and wehicle) the effect is quite small. That's why I did not mention this effect in my answer. Then again, even for liquids the density is a function of pressure! This effect is much-much-much smaller than for gases, but it exists.

Comment: @RifatSafin The pressure of gases does change with height! Usually you do not have to take this effect into account when solving problems because the effect is quite small. If you take a container with height 1 m and fill it with air with usual conditions (room temperature, normal atmospheric preassure) the preasure at the top of container would be 0.01% smaller than the preassure at the bottom. The difference is exactly the same as would be the difference between the preassures at the front wall and the back wall of the 1m-long container moving with $a = 9.8 m / s^2$.

Comment: @lesnik ,But if the container is closed, wouldn't the gas spread out? . Im not able to understand how there would be a height difference.

Comment: @RifatSafin Yes, gas would spread out and fill the closed container. Almost (!) uniformly. Because of gravitational field the preassure and density of the gas would change with height. Quite slightly: much less than 1% per meter of height.

Comment: @lesnik But as much as I know on ideal gases we don't consider the effect of gravity. Is this fact right?

Comment: @RifatSafin It depends on the problem. Usually there is no need to account for gravity forces in such problems because of the very small effect these forces have. But in some problems gravity must be accounted. For example, you need to estimate the difference of atmospheric preassure on the first floor and on the 10-th floor of a building. The difference is noticable, you can feel it sometimes if you use elevator.